# angular factory $resource creating an empty object in database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, post

I have created a REST application using angular $resource but i notice that everytime I make a put or post using a form...the $resource creates an empty entry(object) into database everytime there is a page reload which then displays in the frontend. This also happens when a post/put is not made but just a reload. I dont know if I am correctly using the $save function or is there something with my code

=========================HTML=========================================

```
<div id="hello">
<div class='row'>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="content">Get greeting by ID:</label>
        <div>
            <input type='text' ng-model='$ctrl.getId' name="id" class="form-control"/>
            <span> {{ $ctrl.greeting.content }} </span>
        </div>
        <button ng-click='$ctrl.get();'>Get</button>
        <hr/>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="content">Post new Greeting:</label>
            <div>
                <textarea ng-model='$ctrl.postData' name="content" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button ng-click='$ctrl.post();'>Submit</button>
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="content">Edit greeting by ID:</label>
            <div>
                <input type='text' ng-model='$ctrl.updateId' name="id" class="form-control"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div>
                <textarea ng-model='$ctrl.updateData' name="content" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button ng-click='$ctrl.put();'>Submit</button>
        </div>
        <hr/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <hr/>
        <div class='row' ng-init="$ctrl.listAll()">
            <div ng-repeat="eachElement in $ctrl.greetingList.hello_collection">
                <div  class="col-md-2"> {{ eachElement.id }} </div>
                <div  class="col-md-5"> {{ eachElement.content }} </div>
                <div  class="col-md-5"><button ng-click="$ctrl.remove(eachElement.id)">delete</button></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<hr/>
```

===========================the factory==============================

```
.factory("helloService", ['$resource',
        function($resource) {
            return $resource('/direct/hello/:greetingId.json',
                { greetingId: '@greetingId' }, {
                get: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    params: {greetingId: '@greetingId'},
                    isArray: false
                },
                post: {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=UTF-8'},
                },
                put: {
                    method: 'PUT',
                    params: {greetingId: '@greetingId'}
                },
                remove: {
                    method: 'DELETE',
                    params: {greetingId: '@greetingId'}

                },
                listAll: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    isArray: false
                },
            });
        }
    ])
```

================================the component========================

```
.component('hello', {
        controller: ['helloService',
            function (helloService) {
                var self = this;
                self.greetingList;
                function get() {
                    self.greeting = helloService.get({greetingId: self.getId});
                }
                self.get = get;

                function post() {
                    self.newGreeting = helloService.post({'content': self.postData }, function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                    });
                    self.greetingList.hello_collection.push(self.newGreeting);
                    self.postData = "";
                }
                self.post = post;

                function put() {
                    helloService.put({greetingId: self.updateId}, {'content': self.updateData });
                    var newValue = self.updateData;
                    var greeting = helloService.get({greetingId: self.updateId}, function(data){
                        data.content == newValue;
                        console.log(data);
                        console.log(data.content);
                    });
                    console.log(greeting);
                    /**
                    for (var i = 0; i < self.greetingList.hello_collection.length; i++)
                        {
                            if(self.greetingList.hello_collection[i].greetingId == self.updateId){
                                console.log(self.greetingList.hello_collection[i]);
                                self.greetingList.hello_collection[i].content = self.updateData;
                            }
                        }
                    **/
                    self.updateId, self.updateData = "";                            
                }
                self.put = put;

                function remove(deleteId) {
                    var greeting = helloService.get({greetingId: deleteId})
                    for (var i = 0; i < self.greetingList.hello_collection.length; i++) {
                        if (self.greetingList.hello_collection[i]["id"] == deleteId) {
                            var index = i;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (index >= 0) {
                        self.greetingList.hello_collection.splice(index, 1);
                        helloService.remove({greetingId: deleteId}, function() {
                          greeting.$delete();
                        });                         
                    }                       
                }
                self.remove = remove;
                var greetingList;
                function listAll() {
                    self.greetingList = helloService.listAll();
                }
                self.listAll = listAll;
                var newService = new helloService();
                newService.$save();

            }
        ],
        templateUrl: "./templates/hello.html",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem which gave rise to the above problem was that the front page was still displays deleted(DELETE) data after a page refresh and also after an update (PUT) is made, the old content still displayed on page load. But I solve it my using headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" }

```
angular.module('helloApp', ['ngResource'])
    .factory("helloService", ['$resource',
        function($resource) {
            return $resource('/direct/hello/:greetingId.json',
                { greetingId: '@greetingId' }, {
                get: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    params: {greetingId: '@greetingId'},
                    isArray: false,
                    headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" }
                },
                post: {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=UTF-8'},
                },
                put: {
                    method: 'PUT',
                    params: {greetingId: '@greetingId'},
                    headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" }
                },
                remove: {
                    method: 'DELETE',
                    params: {greetingId: '@greetingId'}
                },
                listAll: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    isArray: false,
                    headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" }
                },
            });
        }
    ])
```

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your component and service to make use of resource.$save() and $resource.remove() as following:

**Updated Service**

```
.factory("helloService", ['$resource',
  function($resource) { 
    return $resource('/direct/hello/:greetingId.json', {
      greetingId: '@greetingId'
    }, {
      get: {
        method: 'GET', 
        params: {
          greetingId: '@greetingId'
        }, 
        isArray: false
      },
      post: {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
        },
      },
      put: {
        method: 'PUT',
        params: {
          greetingId: '@greetingId'
        }
      },
      remove: {
        method: 'DELETE',
        params: {
          greetingId: '@greetingId'
        }

      },
      listAll: {
        method: 'GET',
        isArray: true // <-- this should be true as in a RESTFULL app the
                      //     listAll should expect array of objects as a 
                      //     response i.e.: [{id:1,content:"..."},
                      //     {id:2,content:"..."}]
      },
    });
  }
]);
```

**Updated Component**

```
.component('hello', {
        controller: ['helloService',
            function (helloService) { 
                var self = this;

                function get() {
                    self.greeting = helloService.get({greetingId: self.getId});
                }
                self.get = get; 

                function post() {
                    var greetingItem = new helloService();
                    greetingItem.content = self.postData;
                    greetingItem.$save();
                    self.greetingList.push(greetingItem);
                    self.postData = "";
                }
                self.post = post;

                function put() {
                    var greetingItem = helloService.get({greetingId: self.updateId}, function() {
                      greetingItem.content = self.updateData;
                      greetingItem.$save();
                      console.log(greetingItem);
                      self.updateId = "";
                      self.updateData = "";         
                    });

                }
                self.put = put;

                function remove(deleteId) {
                    var greetingItem = helloService.get({greetingId: deleteId}, function(){
                      for (var i = 0; i < self.greetingList.length; i++) {
                          if (self.greetingList[i].id == deleteId) {
                              var index = i;
                              break;
                          }
                      }
                      greetingItem.$delete({greetingId: deleteId});
                      if (index >= 0) {
                          self.greetingList.splice(index, 1);
                      }                       
                    });
                }
                self.remove = remove;

                var greetingList = [];
                function listAll() {
                    self.greetingList = helloService.listAll();
                }
                self.listAll = listAll;

            }
        ], 
        templateUrl:  "./templates/hello.html"
});
```

Comment: when i remove those lines as you have directed...if i make a new post or put, the page doesn't display the result instantly except after many page refresh but the data is updated in the database.

Comment: Yes, this is because you are assigning the return value of post() as a new object in your collection list in `self.newGreeting = helloService.post(..`, but this is not the correct way to get the new inserted object, the correct way is to use success callback to retrieve it, I've updated the answer to cover this.

Comment: thanks @shadi...but there is still a problem. Any time i perform a delete operation ...on page reload it still display the previous list before the reload but the content deleted is not in the database.

Comment: Actually in your delete operation, you don't need to call `helloService.remove()` at all, using just `greeting.$delete();` is enough to perform the delete.

Comment: Hi, removing `helloService.remove() ` doesn't perform any operation in database. data doesnt get deleted.

Comment: well, since this is getting complex, I've updated your codes to make use of resource.$save() and resource.$remove() methods, this should give you an idea of how could these methods be used to achieve your desired operations, hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Well, thanks for your help but it still display the same result after deleting or updating after page refresh. I think it may be some issues with cache if you have any idea.

Comment: I see, so now does the database contain empty objects any more? also, if you think there is a caching problem, you might want to append arbitrary paramater in page url to reload it without cache like myform?timestamp=1, and then myform?timestamp=2 and so on, this arbitrary param will cause the browser to think it's different url and won't use cache.